# Technical requirements for installing Geoserver and having a web mapping platform

Tags: geoserver, server

I have taken up a new job, and I need to undertake some web mapping sing Geoserver. I have no idea the hardware required to install Geoserver and do web mapping. I know there is a server involved, is it the server that will host my installation and the platform ? I can't quite figure out the whole set up yet.

Comment: What sort of volumes will you be dealing with and what sort of uptime do you need? Geoserver is very easy to set up, and pretty much runs out of the box, but running on one server isn't ideal -- not because there is anything wrong with Geoserver, just that single points of failure are not a good idea. I know much less about Mapserver/Geonode.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my initial question was too broad, am after the technical requirements needed to set up Geoserver and deploy the web mapping platform.

Answer (score 1):

Just start playing!

Get yourself a virtual server (Windows or Linux, whatever you're comfortable with), and install the OpenGeoSuite.

I run a small production server with around 2 GB of ram and two processors and it works fine.

As John Barca says, you can scale up to very big, with load balancing and separate, redundant database servers. But to start with, just a little virtual server will do.

Depending on the job you want to do, if you don't do sysadmin stuff much, something like CartoDB or MapBox might make you more productive, faster, and they handle scale for you.